# How to calculate the total time while excluding the overlapped time in Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with tackling the Gaps and Islands type in this situation.
I want to calculate the total downtime in Microsoft SQL. Is there any I can produce the following output? Thank you!

The actual downtime = Total downtime - overlapped time

[image: Original Data]

[image: Desired Output]

In this case:

Machine A: 14 hours

Machine B: 5 hours but 4 hours overlapped

Machine C: 1 hour

Machine D: 2 hours

Machine E: 1 hour overlapped

Machine F: 2 hours but 1 hour overlapped

In total, it is 19 hours as the actual downtime'

**My table is a query. Please let me know how I can put the query in. Thank you!**

Comment: `select 19 as [Downtime (hours)]` comes to mind, because you provide no explanation for the calculation and that is the simplest way to get your result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just edit so that there is explanation for the calculation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on techniques from Itzik Ben-Gan (noted in the source below).  The solution uses the [DENSE_RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825(v=sql.105).aspx) function.  The code is complete - it can be copied into an SSMS query window and executed.

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetNums', 'IF') IS NOT NULL
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO

/* dbo.GetNums function is from Itzik Ben-Gan's article on packing intervals:
   (http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/). */

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@n AS BIGINT)
  RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
    WITH
      L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
      L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
      L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
      L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
      L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
      L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
      Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
    SELECT TOP (@n) n FROM Nums ORDER BY n;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Production', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.Production;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Production
  (
    production_line INT NOT NULL,
    machine CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    [date] DATE NOT NULL,
    time_started TIME NOT NULL,
    time_completed TIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Production PRIMARY KEY(production_line, machine)
  );

INSERT INTO dbo.Production
    (production_line, machine, [date], time_started, time_completed)
  VALUES
    (1, 'A', '2018-01-16', '00:00:00', '14:00:00'),
    (1, 'B', '2018-01-16', '10:00:00', '15:00:00'),
    (1, 'C', '2018-01-16', '17:00:00', '18:00:00'),
    (1, 'D', '2018-01-16', '21:00:00', '23:00:00'),
    (1, 'E', '2018-01-16', '21:30:00', '22:30:00'),
    (1, 'F', '2018-01-16', '17:00:00', '19:00:00');

/* Algorithm adapted from "Microsoft SQL Server 2012
   High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions" by
   Itzik Ben-Gan (p. 198). */

DECLARE @production_date AS DATE = '2018-01-16';
DECLARE @from AS TIME = '00:00:00';
DECLARE @to AS TIME = '23:59:59';

WITH Hours AS
(
  SELECT
      DATEADD(hour, (nums.n - 1), @from) AS hr
    FROM
      dbo.GetNums(24 /* Hours in a day. */) AS nums
),
Groups AS
(
  SELECT
      H.hr,
      DATEADD(hour, -1 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY H.hr), H.hr) AS grp
    FROM
      dbo.Production AS P
      INNER JOIN Hours AS H ON H.hr BETWEEN P.time_started AND P.time_completed
    WHERE
      p.[date] = @production_date
),
Ranges AS
(
  SELECT
      MIN(hr) AS range_start,
      MAX(hr) AS range_end
    FROM
      Groups
    GROUP BY
      grp
)
SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, range_start, range_end)) AS hours_of_downtime
  FROM
    Ranges

DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
DROP TABLE dbo.Production;
```

EDIT: In response to OP's question about if their data comes from a query.  This modified example removes the temporary `dbo.Production` table, and adds a `Production` Common Table Expression.

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetNums', 'IF') IS NOT NULL
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO

/* dbo.GetNums function is from Itzik Ben-Gan's article on packing intervals:
   (http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/). */

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@n AS BIGINT)
  RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
    WITH
      L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
      L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
      L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
      L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
      L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
      L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
      Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
    SELECT TOP (@n) n FROM Nums ORDER BY n;
GO

/* Algorithm adapted from "Microsoft SQL Server 2012
   High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions" by
   Itzik Ben-Gan (p. 198). */

DECLARE @production_date AS DATE = '2018-01-16';
DECLARE @from AS TIME = '00:00:00';
DECLARE @to AS TIME = '23:59:59';

WITH Hours AS
(
  SELECT
      DATEADD(hour, (nums.n - 1), @from) AS hr
    FROM
      dbo.GetNums(24 /* Hours in a day. */) AS nums
),
Production AS
(
  SELECT
      production_line,
      machine,
      [date],
      time_started,
      time_completed 
    FROM
      production_table
    WHERE
      [date] = @production_date
),
Groups AS
(
  SELECT
      H.hr,
      DATEADD(hour, -1 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY H.hr), H.hr) AS grp
    FROM
      Production AS P
      INNER JOIN Hours AS H ON H.hr BETWEEN P.time_started AND P.time_completed
),
Ranges AS
(
  SELECT
      MIN(hr) AS range_start,
      MAX(hr) AS range_end
    FROM
      Groups
    GROUP BY
      grp
)
SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, range_start, range_end)) AS hours_of_downtime
  FROM
    Ranges

DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If my table is a query, where should I put my query into?

Comment: @Felix: Please see the edit.  Just replace the example query in the `Production AS` Common Table Expression with your query.

Comment: Hi, I just have a quick question: Why do I have to "Declare the production_date as DATE = '2018-01-16' "? Because my table will have many different dates on it.

Comment: Also, when I execute your query according to your instruction. I receive an error: "SQL Error (102): Incorrect Syntax near 'GO'. How can I fix this?

Comment: After I delete the GO in the code, another error comes up as "SQL Error (262): CREATE FUNCTION permission denied in database 'tempdb'
"

Comment: @Felix: [GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) is a batch terminator.  It's necessary after the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.  There was a syntax error in the second code example which I've fixed (a comma was missing after the `machine` attribute).  That might have caused the error.  As for the `production_date` question, your original question didn't mention querying across multiple dates.  You may want to create a new question about packing time intervals across multiple dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, but here is what I did:

1. Combine all records
2. Check for overlaps
3. Get min start and max stop for overlaps
4. Remove overlaps from the original set
5. sum the start/stop deltas for overlaps and non-overlaps

I created a table using your sample data above and got your answer: 19.

And the code is:

```
 WITH aset
 AS (
 SELECT [Machine]
      , [Date]
      , [TimeStarted]
      , TimeCompleted
 FROM   [CEA_DBA].[dbo].[LineInteruptions]
 WHERE  date = '2018-01-16'),
 overlaps
 AS (
 SELECT a.machine
        AS a_machine
      , b.machine
        AS b_machine
      , CASE
            WHEN a.TimeStarted <= b.TimeStarted
            THEN a.TimeStarted
            ELSE b.TimeStarted
        END
        AS timeStarted
      , CASE
            WHEN a.TimeCompleted >= b.TimeCompleted
            THEN a.TimeCompleted
            ELSE b.TimeCompleted
        END
        AS timeCompleted
 FROM   aset
      AS a
        CROSS JOIN aset
      AS b
 WHERE  b.TimeStarted <= a.timeCompleted
        AND b.timecompleted >= a.timecompleted
        AND a.Machine <> b.Machine),
 nonoverlaps
 AS (
 SELECT aset.timeStarted
      , aset.timeCompleted
 FROM   aset
        LEFT OUTER JOIN overlaps
      AS oa ON aset.Machine = oa.a_machine
        LEFT OUTER JOIN overlaps
      AS ob ON aset.Machine = ob.b_machine
 WHERE  oa.a_machine IS NULL
        AND ob.b_machine IS NULL),
 gset
 AS (
 SELECT TimeStarted
      , TimeCompleted
 FROM     overlaps
 UNION ALL
 SELECT timestarted
      , timecompleted
 FROM   nonoverlaps)
 SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, TimeStarted, timeCompleted))
        AS downtime
 FROM   gset;
```

Comment: do you mind if I can have your table code to create a table in SQL Fiddle

Comment: If I have a table as a query, where should I put my query at?

Comment: @Felix Substitute your table name for  [CEA_DBA].[dbo].[LineInteruptions]. The table code is 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LineInteruptions](
 [Machine] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
 [TimeStarted] [time](7) NOT NULL,
 [TimeCompleted] [time](7) NOT NULL,
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO